# Android: add some Chinese characters

Tags: android, unicode, cjk

I have a few Chinese characters that are only by default available in API level 23 and up (they're part of a newer version of Unicode, I think).
I can add a font I downloaded (NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf), which includes these characters, to my project for lower API levels.
My problem is that this file is 16 MB while I only use about 10 characters from it. So is there an easy way to create a custom .otf that only contains these characters? Or can I add these characters to the project in another way?

Comment: I'm trying out the solution proposed there, but uploading takes ages.

Comment: Upload failed: "You cannot upload a font that is greater than 2 megabytes."